# How can I manage and deploy snap packages without using the official Snap store from Canonical?

Tags: snap, puppet, chef

I was wondering if it would be possible to create and self-host a repository of snap packages which could then be deployed / updated via something like Puppet, Chef or Ansible.  Is this feasible, or are there some mechanisms within snaps that would make this impossible?

As a note, the snap store example [referenced here](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/06/24/howto-host-your-own-snap-store/) is now marked as obsolete / no longer compatible with current snapd implementations.

Comment: https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/06/24/howto-host-your-own-snap-store/

Comment: @muru - thanks, but the snap store implementation referenced in that article is now marked as obsolete, and they've removed the relevant application code.  I will edit my question to note that detail.

Comment: Are you asking if you can host your own Snap store/repositories (like a PPA if it were a .deb), or are you asking if you can build and distribute Snap packages without a store? I understand both questions may be a bit similar, but the answers to those questions are more likely to be completely different.

Comment: @Dan - I'm asking if I can build and distribute snap packages without a store (i.e., host them internally on a server, and then use config management to deploy and manage the snaps). We'd be looking to do this internally, and would prefer to not have to go through Canonical sales just to deploy a small set of snap packages.

Comment: @j1mc I updated the question title to try and reflect what you answered in your comments. Please feel free to revert it back to what it was if you believe that's not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't and it's not a priority for the snappy team to support this feature. See the extensive discussion [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/external-repositories/1760) (I'd suggest liking comments on this thread that you agree with).

On the forum I do read about 'branded stores' but, as I understand it, these are kinda subsets of the snappy store? Sorry I can't substantiate this comment better, but the feature you're asking for is simply not supported.